# Longtable header

Tags: longtable

I have a longtable whose header is coming in the previous page instead of the next page. The table is long as well, I tried manually placing \pagebreak to no benefit. Please help why this happening?!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images

\title{trial}
\usepackage{longtable, booktabs}

\begin{document}

%\maketitle

{\scriptsize\tabcolsep = 1.9pt 
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2.1}
\begin{longtable}{@{\extracolsep{1.5pt}}ccccccccccc@{}}
\caption{Trial.}\\
\hline
value & \multicolumn{5}{c}{value} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{value}  \\ 
   \cline{2-6} \cline{7-11}  
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{value} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{value} &  value & \multicolumn{2}{c}{value} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{value} & value \\
 \cline{2-3} \cline{4-5} \cline{7-8}  \cline{9-10} 
  & value & value & value & value & & value & value & value & value &   \\
 \hline
\endfirsthead
\caption{Trial.}\\
\hline
value &   \multicolumn{5}{c}{value} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{value}  \\ 
   \cline{2-6} \cline{7-11}  
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{value} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{value} &  value & \multicolumn{2}{c}{value} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{value} & value \\
 \cline{2-3} \cline{4-5} \cline{7-8}  \cline{9-10} 
  & value & value & value & value & & value & value & value & value &   \\
 \hline
\midrule
   \multicolumn{11}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape Continued on the next page}
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
1 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
2 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
3 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
4 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
5 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
6 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
7 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
8 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
9 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
1 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
2 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
3 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
4 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
5 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
6 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
7 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
8 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
9 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
1 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
2 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
3 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
4 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
5 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
6 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
7 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
8 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
9 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
1 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
2 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
3 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
4 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
5 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
6 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
7 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
8 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
9 & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\ 
\end{longtable}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: there are some issues with longtable page breaking but I've never seen that. please make a small reproducible example so that it can be debugged

Comment: I edited the question with the code, I just added multiple rows so that it extends to multiple pages.

Comment: you have specified the caption goes in the foot not the head.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\caption{Trial.}\\
\hline
value & \multicolumn{5}{c}{value} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{value}  \\ 
    \cline{2-6} \cline{7-11}  
   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{value} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{value} &  value & \multicolumn{2}{c}{value} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{value} & value \\
  \cline{2-3} \cline{4-5} \cline{7-8}  \cline{9-10} 
   & value & value & value & value & & value & value & value & value &   \\
  \hline
\endfirsthead
```

specifies table headings on the first page

```
\caption{Trial.}\\
\hline
value &   \multicolumn{5}{c}{value} & \multicolumn{5}{c}{value}  \\ 
    \cline{2-6} \cline{7-11}  
   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{value} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{value} &  value & \multicolumn{2}{c}{value} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{value} & value \\
  \cline{2-3} \cline{4-5} \cline{7-8}  \cline{9-10} 
   & value & value & value & value & & value & value & value & value &   \\
  \hline
\midrule
    \multicolumn{11}{r}{\footnotesize\itshape Continued on the next page}
\endfoot
```

specifies the table *footer* on all pages except the last

```
\endlastfoot
```

specifies an empty footer on the last page.

So on the first page you get the caption and table column headings at the top and bottom.

I would guess you intended `\endhead` after the `\midrule` before `\endfoot`

Comment: Exactly as intended!

Answer (score 1):

More simple and robust to errors in column headers and captions code you can get by use of the `tabularray` instead `longtable` package. Beside this since you load ˙booktabs` package it is sensible to use rules defined by it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray} 
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[ % defined in tabularray package
caption = {Trial.},
  label = {longtab:trial}
                    ]{colspec = {@{} c *{10}{X[c]} @{}},
                      cell{1}{2,7} = {c=5}{},
                      cell{2}{2,4,7,9} = {c=2}{},
                      rowhead = 1
                      }
% column headers
    \toprule
value   &   value
            &   &   &   &   &   value
                                &   &   &   &   \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-6}  \cmidrule[l]{7-11}
        &   value
            &   &   value
                    &   value
                        &   value
                            &   value
                                &   value
                                    &   value
                                        &   value
                                            &   value   \\
    \cmidrule[lr]{2-3}  \cmidrule[lr]{4-5}
    \cmidrule[lr]{7-8}  \cmidrule[lr]{9-10}
    &   value 
        &   value 
            &   value 
                &   value 
                    &   &   value 
                            &   value 
                                &   value 
                                    &   value   &       \\
    \midrule
% table body
1   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
2   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
3   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
4   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
5   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
6   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
7   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
8   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
9   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\

1   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
2   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
3   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
4   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
5   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
6   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
7   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
8   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
9   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\

1   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
2   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
3   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
4   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
5   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
6   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
7   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
8   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
9   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\

1   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
2   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
3   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
4   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
5   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
6   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
7   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
8   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
9   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Syntax of `tabularray` package is thoroughly described in the package documentation.

[image]

(red lines shows page layout)